# Find max value of a node using xpath in xslt version1.0

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0

I am a new bee to xslt . can someone provide some guidance regarding the below issue
I need to write a template which returns max and min value  node EI from the below input

```
   <Data>
   <EI>110</EI>
    <EI>111</EI>
    <EI>112</EI>
    <EI>113</EI>
     <EI>114</EI>
    <EI>115</EI>
    </Data>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To find the minimum value:

```
/Data/EI[not(. &gt; /Data/EI)][1]
```

To find the maximum value:

```
/Data/EI[not(. &lt; /Data/EI)][1]
```

Comment: Hi mark, can you please help on a similar issue  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19184044/get-max-value-of-a-node-not-working