# XML xpath to find maximum value for a child of particular category

Tags: java, xml, xpath

Consider the given XML

```
<root>
  <ACTS>
    <Act>Play</Act>
    <A>
      <Day>1</Day>
      <time>Fri Feb 28 13:21:42 IST 2014</time>
    </A>
    <A>
      <Day>2</Day>
      <time>Fri Feb 28 13:21:43 IST 2014</time>
    </A>    
  </ACTS>
  <ACTS>
    <Act>Study</Act>
    <A>
      <Day>1</Day>
      <time>Fri Feb 28 13:21:42 IST 2014</time>
    </A>
    <A>
      <Day>2</Day>
      <time>Fri Feb 28 13:21:43 IST 2014</time>
    </A> 
    <A>
      <Day>3</Day>
      <time>Fri Feb 28 13:21:43 IST 2014</time>
    </A>   
  </ACTS>
</root>
```

How can I find Maximum day for Act=Study?
How can I find Minimum day for Act=Study?
is it possible to define this xml in any tuned way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using **XPath 1.0**, which is the only natively one supported by Java, you can only find the maximum/minimum by checking if there is no element larger/smaller than his. To find the `<A/>` tag (or tags, if they share the value) with maximum day, do

```
//ACTS[Act='Study']/A[not(Day < //ACTS[Act='Study']/A/Day)]
```

Be aware of the "set-semantics" of the `<` operator: it returns true, if *any element* on the left side is smaller than *any element* on the right side. Thus, the predicate will return evaluate to true if there are no other `<Day/>` elements with larger value.

For the minimum value, just exchange the operator with `>`.

If you can embed an **XPath 2.0**-capable query processor like Saxon or BaseX, you can use the more comfortable (and probably faster) query

```
max(//ACTS[Act='Study']/A/Day)
```

To find the the actual element with maximum day value, compare with the maximum value:

```
//ACTS[Act='Study']/A[Day = max(//ACTS[Act='Study']/A/Day)]
```

Comment: i'm a newbie to xml and xpath.. could you pls how it is working...
especially i dont understand the following  
    
    `[not(Day <`   
  
Thanks in advance...

Comment: The stuff in brackets is a predicate, which filters the elements (read an XPath tutorial for details). `$set1 < $set2` is true if any element in `$set1` is smaller than any in `$set2`. In `Day < //ACTS[Act='Study']/A/Day` Day is a single element, the right side contains all days. If there's any other day larger than the current one, it is no maximum. And well, `not(...)` performs a boolean not.

Answer (score 0):

This XPath statement will return `<A>` element from `<Child>` element having `Act=Study` with maximum `Day` value :

```
//ACTS[Act='Study']/A/Day[not(. < //ACTS[Act='Study']/A/Day)][1]/..
```

and this one will return `<A>` element with minimum `Day` value :

```
//ACTS[Act='Study']/A/Day[not(. > //ACTS[Act='Study']/A/Day)][1]/..
```

to see how it works to select minimum and maximum value, check a simpler scenario [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18759984/find-max-value-of-a-node-using-xpath-in-xslt-version1-0) (replace `&gt;` and `&lt;` from answer, respectively, with `>` and `<`).

I'm using the same concept from that post to get minimum/maximum `<Day>` element, then select it's parent `<A>` (by using `/..` at the end).

Comment: Thanks for your immediate response